# How to properly normalize multivariate time series data?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, deep-learning, normalization, recurrent-neural-network

My data has three kinds of features, with different distributions and ranges, and I am going to use RNN to model such data. In the process of normalization, my initial thoughts are:

1. compute z-score for features with normal distribution.
2. min-max scale non normal features into range [-1,+1]  (align with the output of relu function).
3. Transform binary features from [0, 1] to [-1, 1].

However, since z-score is in unit of one std, its not in range [-1, +1] as in other two cases. Would this causing any problems? If so, what is the best strategy to normalize?